# Remove dictionary values based on regex?

Tags: python, regex, string, dictionary

I have the following dictionary in Python

```
dict1 = {"key1": 2345, "key2": 356, "key3": 773, "key44": 88, "key333": 12, "key3X": 13}
```

I want to delete keys that do not follow the pattern `"xxx#"` or `"xxx##"`. That is, three characters followed by a one-digit integer or a two-digit integer. Using the above example, this is:

```
new_dict = {"key1": 2345, "key2": 356, "key3": 773, "key44": 88}
```

For one or two keys, the way I would create a new dictionary would be with a list comprehension:

```
small_dict = {k:v for k,v in your_dic.items() if v not in ["key333", "key3X"]}
```

However, how would I use regex/other string methods to remove these strings?

Separate question: What if there's a special exception, e.g. one key I would like to key called `"helloXX"`?

Comment: @KevinMGranger Manually searching, as I did with `small_dict`.

Comment: You've already demonstrated how to filter a dictionary based on a boolean condition, and from that you could easily modify it to use a regex instead.

Comment: @KevinMGranger The exception is the sticking point for me mentally. I would like to filter both keys outside of a pattern specified by regex, or `"helloXX"`? I guess the way to do this would be `new_dict = {k:dict1[k] for k in dict1 for k in [re.match('[^\d\s]+\d{1,2}$', k), "helloXX"}`?

Comment: @ShanZhengYang:  That's a good pattern, but your conditional will fail because `re.match` will return a regex object, not a `str`, so it will not filter correctly.  just use that pattern, not a list that includes the pattern and the exception string.

Comment: @Billy Thank you for the clarification. This is exactly what I was having difficulty understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should match all the keys in your example as well as your exception case:

```
new_dict = {k:dict1[k] for k in dict1 if re.match('[^\d\s]+\d{1,2}$', k)}
```

Using a new example dict with your exception in it:

```
>>> dict1 = {"key1": 2345, "key2": 356, "key3": 773, "key44": 88, "key333": 12, "key3X": 13, "hello13": 435, "hello4325": 345, "3hi33":3}
>>> new_dict = {k:dict1[k] for k in dict1 if re.match('[^\d\s]+\d{1,2}$', k)}
>>> print(new_dict)
{'hello13': 435, 'key44': 88, 'key3': 773, 'key2': 356, 'key1': 2345}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex to match 3 letters, followed by one or two digits, followed directly by the end of the string (`$`):

```
>>> import re
>>> small_dict = {k:v for k,v in dict1.items() if re.match('[a-z]{3}\d{1,2}$',k, re.IGNORECASE)}
>>> small_dict
{'key44': 88, 'key3': 773, 'key1': 2345, 'key2': 356}
```

Note that `re.match` searches for the regex at the beginning of the string : `"123key123"` wouldn't match for example.

If there are exceptions, you could add them after having filtered the keys.
If you want to do it in one go:

```
small_dict = {k:v for k,v in dict1.items() if re.match('[a-z]{3}\d{1,2}$',k, re.IGNORECASE) or k in ["hello12", "hello34"]}
```

Comment: The last line was what I was confused by. Thank you for this!

Answer (score 1):

Just another variation:

```
import re

dict1 = {"key1": 2345, "key2": 356, "key3": 773, "key44": 88, "key333": 12, "key3X": 13}

rx = re.compile(r'^[A-Za-z]{3}\d{1,2}$')

new_dict = {key: dict1[key] for key in dict1 if rx.search(key)}
print(new_dict)
# {'key44': 88, 'key3': 773, 'key1': 2345, 'key2': 356}
```